# Select List to Display

Tags: c#, .net

```
if (gardenvlist.Count() == days)
{
    var g = gardenvlist;
}
if (oceanvlist.Count() == days)
{
    var o = oceanvlist;
}
if (cityvlist.Count() == days)
{
    var c = cityvlist;
}

var final = g.Union(o).Union(c);

if (final.Count() > 0)
{
    return new ObjectResult(final);
}

return NotFound();
```

So, what I have over here is I wanted to check if the gardenvlist are available within the period. If the list is available in the period, select the list. After that check the oceanvlist and so on. Next, it will check that if the final result contains any lists. If there's one or many lists, return those lists else return false.

Sorry if my explanation is not clear enough. I'm new to programming.

Comment: What's the point of declaring those variables inside the `if` blocks? They cease to exist as soon as that block completes. You should do some reading on scope of variable.

Comment: Variables `g o and c` need to be declared outside the `if` block or your code will not compile.

Comment: You also need to check if each one them is initialized before using them to create `final`.

Comment: Why not do `var final gardenvlist.Union(oceanvlist).Union(cityvlist);`? Even if you moved `g`, `o`, and `c` out of the `if` blocks, they'll be a null value.

Comment: @AustinWBryan Because I'm trying to check if the lists are true to the if statement. I'm trying to select only the ones that match the if statement.

Comment: Right, but say `gardenvlist` doesn't match. What do you expect `g` to be?

Comment: @AustinWBryan that's true. Thank you

Comment: @supsupdb I would expect them to be an empty list, or not add them at all. That being said, those one-lettered variables need not be there at all.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the `Select` in each `if` condition because you do not do anything with the projection (select). Also, declare your `final` variable at the beginning and add to it inside the `if` blocks.

```
var rateGroupIds = new List<int>();

if (gardenvlist.Count() == days)
{
    rateGroupIds.AddRange(gardenvlist.Select(x => RateGroupID));
}
if (oceanvlist.Count() == days)
{
    rateGroupIds.AddRange(oceanvlist.Select(x => RateGroupID));
}
if (cityvlist.Count() == days)
{
    rateGroupIds.AddRange(cityvlist.Select(x => RateGroupID));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var final = new List<T>();

// Add all the lists only if they match
UnionIfMatches(gardenvlist);
UnionIfMatches(oceanvlist);
UnionIfMatches(cityvlist);

if (final.Count() > 0)
    return new ObjectResult(final);

return NotFound();

// ---- Local Functions ---- //

// Adds the list to final if it matches
void UnionIfMatches(List<T> list)
{
    if (ListMatches(list))
        final.Union(list);
}

// Checks if the list matches
bool ListMatches(List<T list> => list.Select(x => xmethod.RateGroupID.Count() == days);
```

You used the same code 3 times, so I just moved the testing if it matches into a new function `ListMatches()` to make it easier. I then made a second function that will add in that list only if it matches.

I don't know what type you were using, because you used `var`, so I'm just guessing it was a `List<T>`. If it wasn't, just swap it out with the real class and it should still work.

These local functions are only usable and visible from within the scope of the function, which is really useful.

I couldn't test this, so let me know how this works.